# Packing files in a directory to a single file in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, io

My little program (called MrPackerUnpacker) takes a full path as an argument and creates a single file that can be unpacked to a folder later to reveal the packed files.

Given the following 2 files in folder: /Users/koraytugay/Pictures:

```
a.txt
koray.txt
```

where contents of the files are just "a" and "koray" saved in UTF-8 encoding, the created file will have the name Pictures.pckr and the contents:

```
0000 0000 0000 0005 0000 0000 0000 0001
612e 7478 7461 0000 0000 0000 0009 0000
0000 0000 0005 6b6f 7261 792e 7478 746b
6f72 6179
```

where

```
0000 0000 0000 0005
```

represents 5 bytes, length of the name of the first file packed.

```
0000 0000 0000 0001
```

represents 1 byte, length of the contents of the first file packed.

```
612e 7478 74
```

represents the filename of the first file packed. (a.txt in this case).

```
61
```

represents the contents of the first file. (simply a in this case).

I think you get the idea how I modeled the "packed file". I have not yet implemented unpacking a packed file, I would highly appricate if you can review the code for my packing a folder:

**MrPackerUnpacker.java**

```
import biz.tugay.mrpackerunpacker.PackerUnpacker;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class MrPackerUnpacker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Make sure the user is calling the application the right way.
        // Sample: java -jar MrPackerUnpacker pack /Users/koraytugay/Pictures
        if (args == null || args.length != 2) {
            printSampleUsageToUser();
            return;
        }

        // First argument must be a valid PackerUnpacker choice!
        final String packUnpackUserInput = args[0];
        if (!packUnpackUserInput.equals(PackerUnpacker.CHOICE_PACK)
                && !packUnpackUserInput.equals(PackerUnpacker.CHOICE_UNPACK)) {
            printSampleUsageToUser();
            return;
        }

        final Path path = Paths.get(args[1]);

        final PackerUnpacker packerUnpacker = new PackerUnpacker(packUnpackUserInput, path);
        try {
            packerUnpacker.packUnpack();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void printSampleUsageToUser() {
        final String sampleUsageDirective = "Sample usage: java -jar MrPackerUnpacker (" + PackerUnpacker.CHOICE_PACK + "|" + PackerUnpacker.CHOICE_UNPACK + ") $fullPath ";
        System.out.println(sampleUsageDirective);
    }
}
```

**PackerUnpacker.java**

```
package biz.tugay.mrpackerunpacker;

import biz.tugay.mrpackerunpacker.pack.Packer;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class PackerUnpacker {

    public static final String CHOICE_PACK = "pack";
    public static final String CHOICE_UNPACK = "unpack";
    public static final String EXTENSION = ".pckr";

    private final String packUnpackUserInput;
    private final Path path;

    public PackerUnpacker(final String packUnpackUserInput, final Path path) {
        this.packUnpackUserInput = packUnpackUserInput;
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void packUnpack() throws IOException {
        if (!Files.exists(path)) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("The path you are trying to pack/unpack does not seem to exist!");
        }

        if (packUnpackUserInput.equals(CHOICE_PACK)) {
            packPath();
        }

        if (packUnpackUserInput.equals(CHOICE_UNPACK)) {
            unpackPath();
        }
    }

    private void packPath() throws IOException {
        final Packer packer = new Packer(path);
        packer.pack();
    }

    private void unpackPath() {
        // Not implemented yet...
    }

}
```

**Packer.java**

```
package biz.tugay.mrpackerunpacker.pack;

import biz.tugay.mrpackerunpacker.PackerUnpacker;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Packer {

    private final Path pathToPack;

    public Packer(final Path pathToPack) throws IOException {
        final boolean isPathToPackDirectory = Files.isDirectory(pathToPack);
        if (!isPathToPackDirectory) {
            throw new IOException("If you are trying to pack a path, it must be a directory!");
        }
        this.pathToPack = pathToPack;
    }

    public void pack() throws IOException {
        final PackFile packFile = new PackFile(pathToPack);

        final File output = new File(pathToPack.getFileName().toString() + PackerUnpacker.EXTENSION);

        final DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output));

        for (PackedFileMeta packedFileMeta : packFile.getPackFileMetas()) {
            dataOutputStream.writeLong(packedFileMeta.getFilenameLength());
            dataOutputStream.writeLong(packedFileMeta.getFileLength());
            dataOutputStream.write(packedFileMeta.getFileNameUTF8Encoded());
            IOUtils.copyLarge(new FileInputStream(packedFileMeta.getFilePath().toFile()), dataOutputStream);
        }

        dataOutputStream.flush();
        dataOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

**PackFile.java**

```
package biz.tugay.mrpackerunpacker.pack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PackFile {

    private List<PackedFileMeta> packedFileMetas = new ArrayList<>();

    public PackFile(final Path pathToPack) throws IOException {
        DirectoryStream<Path> pathToPackDirectoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(pathToPack);
        for (Path path : pathToPackDirectoryStream) {
            if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
                continue; // We do not recursivly pack folders, only files in a folder.
            }
            if (path.getFileName().toString().startsWith(".")) {
                continue; // Skip hidden files!
            }
            final PackedFileMeta packedFileMeta = new PackedFileMeta(path);
            packedFileMetas.add(packedFileMeta);
        }
    }

    public List<PackedFileMeta> getPackFileMetas() {
        return packedFileMetas;
    }
}
```

**PackedFileMeta.java**

```
package biz.tugay.mrpackerunpacker.pack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class PackedFileMeta {

    private final Path filePath;
    private long filenameLength;
    private long fileLength;
    private byte[] fileNameUTF8Encoded;

    public PackedFileMeta(Path filePath) throws IOException {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        fileNameUTF8Encoded = filePath.getFileName().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        filenameLength = fileNameUTF8Encoded.length;
        fileLength = Files.size(filePath);
    }

    public Path getFilePath() {
        return filePath;
    }

    public long getFilenameLength() {
        return filenameLength;
    }

    public byte[] getFileNameUTF8Encoded() {
        return fileNameUTF8Encoded;
    }

    public long getFileLength() {
        return fileLength;
    }
}
```

I am more interested in the readability of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the readability of this code is OK. Entities are quite well structured and an effort to respect the SRP principle is seen.

### General Design

However, I would suggest a few renaming and design changes. The `PackerUpacker` class resembles a factory, because it instantiates the business logic entities (`Packer` or `Unpacker`). But also it chooses which one to use and triggers the main action: this is too much for it, so let's separate the roles.

We can introduce an interface that provides access to the main action:

```
public interface PathProcessor {

  void processPath(Path pathToProcess) throws IOException;

}
```

It may also be seen as an abstract class, because both the implementors might share some similarities (ex. path validation).

`PathProcessor` will be implemented/extended by both `Packer` or `Unpacker` classes.

`PathProcessorFactory` (former `PackerUnpacker`) will decide, depending on the user's input arg, which entity to instantiate:

```
public static PathProcessor newPathProcessor(String userChoice) {
  // instantiate and return `Packer` or `Unpacker` depending on the arg
}
```

The instructions in the main method now become:

```
PathProcessor pathProcessor = PathProcessorFactory.newPathProcessor(packUnpackUserInput);
pathProcessor.processPath(path);
```

### Other

#### `Packer`

The streams inside `pack()` are not wrapped in a try-with-resources, but should be, to prevent from leaving an unclosed stream in case of exception.

#### `PackFile`

The idea to separate it into a dedicated class is not clear. (BTW, it's not a good practice to include much logic into constuctors, neither to throw checked exceptions from them). Its only role is to wrap `packedFileMetas`, so why not producing them in a utility method, ex. `public static List<PackedFileMeta> collectFilesToPack(Path folderToPack)`?

And there should be a try-with-resources wrapping the initialization of `pathToPackDirectoryStream`.

To check whether a file is hidden or not, `path.getFileName().toString().startsWith(".")` is not reliable, because a file name may begin with a dot without the file being hidden. A better way to check is `Files.isHidden(Path)`.

#### `PackedFileMeta`

All the fields should be `final`.

Since this object is instantiated only in `PackFile` collecting sequence and is placed in the same package, I'd suggest to reduce its visibility (and of its methods also) to package level, but this is a very minor issue.

Comment: Thank your for your valuable response. Actually, I forgot to turn out to encapsulate the filename in `PackFile`.